# PHP/mySQL Like function does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query in PHP but I can't get `Like` to work.

Here is the code:

```
$var = $_GET['q'];
$trimmed = trim($var);
$query = "SELECT * FROM vm_regiony WHERE nazev LIKE "%$trimmed%" order by id     LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
  echo "nothing";
  echo "<br />";
  echo $trimmed;
}else{
  while($rene=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $jmeno = $rene['nazev'];
    echo '<a id="hled" onclick="javascript:vybrat()">'.$jmeno.'</a>';
```

Comment: A little code formatting please. That hurts my eyes.

Comment: i was just about to fix it too lol couldn't understand a word..

Comment: Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one you need to use single quotes there

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vm_regiony WHERE nazev LIKE '%$trimmed%' order by id LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks you really much man, really quick answer THANKS!

Comment: Or escape the double quotes - but single quotes is simpler :-)

Comment: no problem - to ensure fast response in the future you should check this answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, i was waiting, bacause there was 10 miutes remaining, and Ive forgot about it :D sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vm_regiony 
          WHERE nazev LIKE '%' . $trimmed . '%' 
          ORDER BY id LIMIT 10";
```